# How can I open emulator in flutter edit android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I use android studio, and then I open emulator see this error message

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A) INFO | 
Found systemPath C:\Users\ehdgk\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\ ERROR |
 Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR |
 is an experimental feature. ERROR | 
Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO 
| Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\ehdgk\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | 
Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO |
```

help guys, thx

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si2zp.png)
I tried many thing, but this is I don't know

Comment: It is saying you are trying to run multiple emulators at the same time

Comment: i feel a quick fix can be to delete the existing emulator and create a new one and try again..

Answer (score 0):

When the device is running and you can not see it, click on **Device Manager tab**. if you can not see this tab, go to `View/Tool Windows /`and navigate to end of the long list. you can see `Running Devices` and click it. now you can see the device.

Comment: Does this answer helped?@dhjjj